# Why are subsequent <script> being fetched immediately without an async tag

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, render-blocking

[image: script async & defer]

According to this image by default HTML parsing should pause when it encounters an external  and wait until the script is downloaded and executed before continuing.

I've been testing this and I can't replicate this logic.

[image: scripts requested at same time]

I've put in a few sample request after my initial  request with no async tag but they all seem to be requested simultaneously

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>Testing</title>
    <script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <img
      src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQReLvoUiu3NJ_g63RtEws3IN9N7fGp6dHRDEirrJEIZ9wW4LED"
    />
  </body>
</html>
```

I would expect from what [I've read](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/critical-rendering-path/adding-interactivity-with-javascript#parser_blocking_versus_asynchronous_javascript) that the second highcharts request wouldn't be initiated until the first script has been fetched and executed due to HTML parsing being paused. On Chrome 75. Does chrome async by default?

Comment: I don't think you are taking into account the way HTTP/TCP is used to share a single TCP connection to transfer several (up to 5 depending on browser) resource files _simultaneously_. So they get transferred virtually at the same time, but then are parsed one-by-one in the order they appear in the HTML file if there is no async/defer attributes.

Comment: Browsers may optimize page loading by *pre-fetching* assets that it determines it will have to fetch later anyway. As long as order of execution (including HTML parsing) is preserved, this is an abstraction that makes no difference other than making the page load more efficiently.